# Workshop subpanel with possible solar backfeed

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, conduit, solar-panels

Needing to run power from the residence to the workshop. the need is 220v for the welder in addition to overhead lighting, the run is 375'....what wire and conduit size is needed?

If in the future, solar panels are installed on the workshop what wiring and conduit is needed to feed back to the house?

Comment: What is the expected load for the shop , what is the size of the solar system. You are talking about an interactive solar system that connects to your line I hope.

Comment: How big is this shop, and is the welder the only major power-tool concern here?  How big is the welder (I1eff/I1max from the nameplate) for that matter?